# Python doesn't print with import scapy

Tags: python, printing, import, scapy

When I enter this code:

```
print "hhhh"
from scapy.all import sniff
print "bbbb"
```

this is the output:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Tamir/PycharmProjects/SIP/main.py
hhhh
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why doesn't the second print (of "bbbb") work?
When I put the import line in a comment, or import another library, it works.

Comment: The import is not working. That throws an exception and the program exits before ever reaching the line that prints `"bbbb"`.

Comment: @RafaelBarros, then the exit code should not be 0 and there should be a traceback, `ImportError:...`

Comment: @user3146359, where are you running this, pycharm?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm running it on "JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1"

Comment: @user3146359, if you add `print(sniff)` do you see any output? Your code does not error as you have a 0 exit status, the warning also proves the import succeeds so you should see the print output

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, if I change the `print "bbbb"` to `print(sniff)` or to `print(sniff(count=1))`, I get the same output as before. If I change it to `print(sniff())` it keeps on running, probably because it keeps on sniffing.

Comment: @user3146359 So the code keeps running with print(sniff())?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, yes

Comment: Try adding this first  `import logging;logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)` then see if it shows the print

Comment: I've tried this already, it only makes the warning disappear. The output is `C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Tamir/PycharmProjects/SIP/main.py
hhhh

Process finished with exit code 0`

Answer (score 0):

**sys.stdout** is redirected to readline console. It seems not working well with pycharm in this way.
Please check: "PYTONPATH\Lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows__init__.py"

[image: scapy\arch\windows__init__.py]

**temporary solution**: redirect stdout to the original one

try this:

```
import sys
print "hhhh"
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
from scapy.all import sniff
sys.stdout =  orig_stdout
print "bbbb"
```