# Python pyreadline cmd/PyCharm

Tags: python, cmd, scapy

I'm trying to use scapy in windows. On the internet it says that i have to install some additional packages. One of them is 'pyreadline'.
If I install all of them, I can use scapy from the cmd, but then I get the warning

```
Warning: __del__:don't know how to close the file descriptor. Bugs ahead! Please report this bug.
```

I get this warnings after using sniff, send and other functions.

But, if i'm running scapy from a python script (PyCharm), after the line

```
from scapy.all import sniff
```

no other line is executed. There is no exception, but in the console it doesn't show anything, including print.

If i don't install the package 'pyreadline', after i run scapy in the cmd, it shows strange symbols instead of the '>>>'. But, in the PyCharm it works and doesn't have the problem i mentioned before.

Does anyone know what is the problem? How to fix it?

Comment: please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812350/python-doesnt-print-with-import-scapy

Comment: @Jerry_Y, It's my own question...

Comment: yes....I just find out that.